# How can a custom Stream type influence the position info. in Parsec?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm using Parsec with a custom `Stream` type. This stream is essentially `String` but sometimes it expands input it finds in the string into other strings (think alias expansion). For example, given "§4.1 ¶3" it might feed "Section 4.1 paragraph 3" to the parser.

I have this all working. My types look like:

```
data DealiasingStream = ...
instance (Monad m) => Stream DealiasingStream m Char where ...

type ShellParser = Parsec DealiasingStream ()
```

Notice that the dependent type of `DealiasingStream` is just `Char`. This allows my parsers (well, my `ShellParser`s to use all the standard character parsers.

My question is about getting Parsec to report the positions in terms of the original input to my stream. The documentation for `Stream` says:

> A `Stream` instance is responsible for maintaining the "position within the stream" in the stream state `s`. This is trivial unless you are using the monad in a non-trivial way.

Indeed, my stream type knows what position it wants to report at any given moment... but I don't see how to get Parsec to use it! Parsec seems to maintain its own `SourcePos` as part of its internal `State`. And this seems to be updated by the various `token` prims, and hence for the standard `Char` parsers, out of my control.

How is one supposed to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your understanding — there's no easy way to control the position without rewriting functions such as `char`.

What the documentation means is that the `Stream` instance is responsible for recording the position information *inside* the tokens. That information then can be used in functions like `token` or `tokenPrim` (by supplying appropriate position-calculating functions to them).

Thus, you have to wrap `Char` into a datatype that includes position information and rewrite the basic functions using the primitives like `token` or `tokenPrim` that are flexible about the position calculation.

Comment: Hmmm... well, I really don't want to change the underlying element type from `Char`.  Losing the convienence of `Char` is a big price to pay. And, seems awkward: That the `Stream` should have to encode the position information in the elements themselves, so that `token` (and friends) can extract it again (and call `setPosition`?). I think it makes sense that Parsec keeps position "on the side", but there should be some interface with the `Stream` for it.

Comment: Keeping position information inside the tokens is a pretty standard practice in parsers. How would such an interface that you talk about look like? There are several reasons why `uncons` shouldn't set the position information through something like `setPosition`. The only improvement I can see for Parsec is to create a class of tokens that would, for each token, give access to its location and its underlying "data".

Comment: I think the situation is confounded by the fact that with Parsec (and often Antlr), one often conflates the lexical and grammar phases. Hence, the stream is returning `Char`, but the concept of _token_ is just a particular parser. So, I'd prefer not to burden all the `Char`s with position information, as I only need it at the token level.

Comment: My solution has been to add a parser that returns the original source position (by calling `getInput` and extracting from the stream), and calling that at the start and end of my token parser, and expressly encoding those positions in the token return type. This gets me the best of both worlds: At the lexical level, it is all just parsers over `Char`, but at the token level (and above), those return types have location information. This means I'm totally ignoring Parsec's location information (and computation). I wonder if always factoring that out into the stream makes more sense.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Do you have your code published anywhere?

Comment: Sure: It's the parser in the aliases2 branch of Plush (https://github.com/mzero/plush/tree/aliases2/src/Plush/Parser) -- The file `Aliases.hs` implements the `Stream` instance I'm using. You can find the main grammar in `Commands.hs` and the lexical levels of it in `Tokens.hs`. See `tok_word` in the later file for an example of a place were the location information is grabbed.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a new `SourcePos` with the functions in `Text.Parsec.Pos`, and set it into the parser with `setPosition` in `Text.Parsec.Prim`.

Edit:

I'm not sure why you need a custom stream, since you are not changing the token type.  You should be able to use a standard `Char` parser, and perform expansions and position updates in your `whitespace` rule.  I have done this using `cpp` to expand macros, and use a custom `whitespace` rule to look for `#line` commmands, which I use to update the position using `setPosition`.  You could use it to look for expansions, and modify the input stream by prepending the expansion to `getInput`, and setting the result back into the parser with `setInput`.  The documentation for `setInput` suggests its use for expanding `#include` directives, which is essentially the same problem.

Comment: Only, the `Stream` instance never sees the `Parsec` parser, so there is no way for the Stream to call `setPosition`. I suppose I could do some kind of tying the knot trick so the stream can hang onto the parser, but that seems awkward.

Comment: I can't do it in a `lexeme` like parser because while reading a `Char`, the current "word" may expand into a string that "spills" out past the parser where `lexeme` was called. Put it another way, lexical elements may expand into multiple elements of which only the prefix matches the grammar element being parsed. In your case, `#line` commands never change the parse beyond the current `lexeme`.